# Problems with --with-registry-auth option, doesnt work with AWS container repositories

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm

When we want create a swarm service from a docker HUB repositories we need do the follows steps

1) **docker login** (dockerHUB login)

2) **docker-machine ssh manager_name "docker service create -p 80:5000 --name web --with-registry-auth repository:latest"**

However if we try a similar command for AWS EC2 container repository this doesnt work.

For example

Im trying create a swarm service from an image that are located in my AWS EC2 container repository.

I have tried with theses commands

1) I've create a login token command with

**aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1**

2) Run the login token command that was returned in the previous step.

3) Run swarm command

**docker-machine ssh *manager_name* "docker service create -p 80:5000 --name web --with-registry-auth *URL_repository*:latest"**

But doesnt download the images

**Note**:The hosts are on virtualbox

Comment: Did step 2 return login succeeded? What happens when you just try docker run on the AWS ECR image, does it check the ecr?

Comment: Yes, step 2 succeeded. And If I do **docker run -d -p 80:5000 URL_repository:latest** (without docker swarm) it works

Comment: Are you running the ecr get-login on the docker hosts that will be running the containers?

Comment: Also, can you download the image on the swarm master?

Comment: Yes, I can do the pull on my manager and then I can create a service but I want to understand why the credential aren't send with the command.

Comment: Sorry NHol, I've made a mistake, I could do a pull when my host is on AWS EC2 instance but not when it over virtualbox. Anyway thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a bug with some versions, its suggested it's working in Swarm 1.2.3

https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/1484

Also info specific to docker engine

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24372

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
eval $(docker-machine env manager_name)
docker login -u XXXX -p YYYYY registryUrl:5000

docker push registryUrl:5000/my-image:latest (optional)

docker service create -p 80:5000 --name web  --with-registry-auth registryUrl:5000/my-image:latest
```